# Magento, Postfix, or Elastic Mail adding slashes

Tags: email, postfix, magento

Magento transactional emails somehow get additional escape characters added to the headers.

Magic_quotes are disabled in PHP.

Postfix uses Elastic Email as a relay. According to Elastic, e-mail are received correctly.

Then majority of clients receive the emails correctly, except those who are behind messagelabs.com filter. After reviewing the logs, the messages are rejected by messagelabs.com because additional slashes are added to the emails.

Has anyone ever come across this issue? Which piece could be at fault?
Again, majority of customers receive emails perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a bug in Elastic Email service. After reporting it to them, they fixed it within a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "perfectly fine", do you mean that most customers receive e-mails that don't have slashes in them?  Or are you simply complaining about messagelabs rejecting your e-mails?

As far as the extra quotes, if it's really happening to everyone, I'll wager that you're not really turning off `magic_quotes_gpc` and `magic_quotes_runtime` -- you've probably turned it off in the main config, and then something's turning it back on (a rogue `.htaccess` file, for instance).  Double (and triple) check by running `phpinfo()` in the same directory as the script that's causing the trouble.

Based on your comments, I'm going to have to say that it's a messagelabs problem -- if you send out an e-mail and it gets to the recipient differently to how you sent it, it's the fault of some intermediary mangling the data in transit.  I can't offer any suggestions to fix it, however; I can only shake my head at the continued insanity of the world.

Comment: Thank you womble, by perfectly fine I mean that non-messagelabs customers do not have slashes added to their headers. I've reviewed detailed headers on other accounts, and they are clean. Is this a known Messagelabs issue? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: P.S. And yes, gpc, runtime, and even sybase magic quotes are turned off.